# Problem with USB RFID Reader and Raspberry pi 4

Tags: usb, pi-4, linux, python-3, rfid

Firstly I'm just a beginner trying to get into pi world so my knowledge is minimal at this point.

I'm trying to make USB RFID card reader work on raspberry like it works on my Windows pc, imitate keyboard and work just as i pressed numbers on keyboard followed by an enter. It did worked with other device in the past. I have a terminal/console app (in python) that reads input from terminal and sends it further to database which works fine

My Raspberry model is Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4 p (from `cat /proc/device-tree/model`)
Rfid card reader does lit up and make sound when it reads card but raspberry doesn't register any input neither in terminal nor text editor as if nothing happened.

As You can tell I'm inexperienced with it but
so far I figured that it is not listed as `ttyusb0`, but I found something under `dev/input/by-id/` like usb-Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315.

I've tried running `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` with no luck.

I've tried finding solution in asked questions but they seem too advanced for me.
In those questions people asked for those commands logs so I'll add them at the bottom.
For some more useful context I ran following commands:

```
lsusb:

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID ffff:0035  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

sudo lshw -c input:

description: Keyboard
product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
vendor: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd
physical id: 3
bus info: usb@1:1.3
version: 1.00
serial: 08FF20140315
capabilities: usb-1.10
configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
```

dmesg output

```
[    2.206436] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=0035, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.206456] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.206473] usb 1-1.3: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[    2.206489] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd
[    2.206504] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 08FF20140315
[    2.222584] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:FFFF:0035.0001/input/input0
[    2.285895] hid-generic 0003:FFFF:0035.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input0
[    2.288506] usbhid 1-1.3:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```

I do think that the problem is `couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint`

full dmesg output: https://pastebin.com/CBBnr0JP

PS my first question here don't be too harsh

Comment: Have you tried the script in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071272/linux-command-to-read-rfid-usb-port

Comment: As far as i understand this would read input directly from file/event without relaying on emulating keyboard right? It might work but i kinda build my script around it and  need to redo the part that collects data. it still will require python terminal running and listening on input. I was just wondering if i'm missing something more trivial.

Comment: Possibly but thought it may be worth checking the device actually links.  I never did get a barcode reader to work as keyboard wedge so went for programmed input.

Comment: I've had some success with that sort of device but I went the other way and wrote a daemon that continuously looks for and grabs ***exclusive*** access to that type of device - because otherwise the unit looks *just* like a keyboard the Linux kernel grabs it and treats it as a keyboard device. *BTW Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavour of the Stack Exchange network. If you haven't done so yet I recommend doing the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) - and for the next 3-4 days that will also give your Avator a hat to wear during this (2020) year's WinterBash.*

Comment: Ah, here was the inspiration for my efforts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415306/4805858